# How to apply styles and css and bootstrap cdn in window.print() when using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want get Print  From my component in Vuejs.

Also I want apply my css and bootsrap in window.print()

I use `window.print()` in `mounted` Like this :

```
       export default {
             mounted() {        
                  window.print();

               }
          }
```

But CSS and Bootstrap have not been applied to the print screen.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

**UPDATE**:
I use adminlte Template.It may be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can have two ways to achieve this

```
PrintScreen(el)
{
    let printWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');

    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById(el).innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    printWindow.document.close(); // IE >= 10
    printWindow.focus(); //  IE >= 10*/

    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Or

You can use a wrapper to do this stuff
[Npm Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-to-paper)

```
npm install vue-html-to-paper
```

Comment: how to add css in vue-html-to-paper?

Comment: i use vue-html-to-paper  but element is Messed up.i add css like this :`styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './style/printStyle.css'
  ]`

Comment: Can you please try above method to print

Comment: i use `window` like above And i insert bootstrap like this:    `printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">');` in  `head` tag

Comment: Try like this  import your CSS like this for media

 <link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen,print'>

or 

<link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='all'>



Step -2 move your print function to onCreated hook